# How do you solve a system of equations with Neumann type boundary conditions using Eigen?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm trying to write a small FEM solver for a structural problem. I'm writing it in C++ and using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for the matrix operations. I'm trying to solve the problem Ka=f, where K is a sparse n-by-n matrix and f is a sparse 1-by-n vector. I want to apply a Neumann type boundary condition on the solution a.

How do I achieve this using Eigen? Or am I thinking about the problem completely wrong?

I can't produce a MWE of what I want to achieve, but here's a skeleton MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // K is supposed to be positive definite
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> K;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> f;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> a;
    K.resize(6,6);
    f.resize(6,1);
    // fill them with some arbitrary numbers...
    K.coeffRef(0,0)=127700;K.coeffRef(0,1)=127700;K.coeffRef(0,2)=127700;K.coeffRef(0,3)=127700;K.coeffRef(0,4)=127700;K.coeffRef(0,5)=127700;
    K.coeffRef(1,0)=127700;K.coeffRef(1,1)=39179.1;K.coeffRef(1,2)=-107963;K.coeffRef(1,3)=-294.578;K.coeffRef(1,4)=-19736.8;K.coeffRef(1,5)=-38884.5;
    K.coeffRef(2,0)=127700;K.coeffRef(2,1)=-107963;K.coeffRef(2,2)=-19736.8;K.coeffRef(2,3)=39179.1;K.coeffRef(2,4)=294.578;K.coeffRef(2,5)=-39473.7;
    K.coeffRef(3,0)=127700;K.coeffRef(3,1)=-294.578;K.coeffRef(3,2)=39179.1;K.coeffRef(3,3)=-10015.7;K.coeffRef(3,4)=-107963;K.coeffRef(3,5)=-39179.1;
    K.coeffRef(4,0)=127700;K.coeffRef(4,1)=-19736.8;K.coeffRef(4,2)=294.578;K.coeffRef(4,3)=-107963;K.coeffRef(4,4)=-19736.8;K.coeffRef(4,5)=-39179.1;
    K.coeffRef(5,0)=127700;K.coeffRef(5,1)=-38884.5;K.coeffRef(5,2)=-39473.7;K.coeffRef(5,3)=-39179.1;K.coeffRef(5,4)=-39179.1;K.coeffRef(5,5)=-39473.7;
    f.coeffRef(5,0)=1.0f;
    Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> solver;
    solver.compute(K);
    // How to apply boundary conditions on specific values on a?
    a = solver.solve(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Few things: `f` and `a` are almost always dense vectors (i.e. `Eigen::VectorX<float>`). As written, `a = solver.solve(f);` wouldn't compile unless you added something silly like `a = solver.solve(f).sparseView();` Secondly, your Neumann boundary conditions are included in your `f`. If you know how to define your `K` coefficients, then `f` is pretty similar.

Comment: In the the case of strucual analysis using FEM typically something like more than 90% of f will be zero. Is it still a good idea to have it as dense vector? Even for scenarious where n is over 100k?

Regarding the boundary conditions. For a structrual problem the solution a contains the solved for displacement, and f is the load vector. I have a hard time understanding how prescribed displacement on a is to be translated to the load vector f.

Could you point me in the right direction with some general example on how to apply boundary conditions on different quantities? thanks :)

Comment: A dense vector with 100k doubles is 800 kb, which is quite small unless you are storing many of these vectors. You can pass `f` as a `SparseVector<float>` but I would be surprised if you saw any beneficial change in performance. If your matrix is 100k x 100k, you should absolutely use a sparse matrix representation!

For a prescribed displacement, that is actually a "Dirichlet" boundary condition, which is handled a bit differently. The easiest way is to modify the stiffness matrix. For example, if you want to enforce `a(1)=f(1)`, set `K(1,1) = 1` and all other `K(1,j) = 0`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a dense matrix for `f`!

How about the case where `a(i)=0` or any arbitrary value, rather than  `a(1)=f(1)` as in your example?